# solve error in connection between sql server 2008 r2 with java in eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to connect SQL server 2008 r2 with my java application using microsoft JDBC sqljdbc_4.0 driver in eclipse IDE, I goggled several time with JDBC connection between java and sql server 2008 and I have tried some of but getting same error message, So lastly am decided to put the question here with error message what am getting than, i can get know what wrong am doing?

I followed [a link](http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/connecting-to-sql-server-from-java/)! link for connectivity with SQL Server and Java.

My java program:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connect
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String userName = "Abhishek";
        String password = "abhishek-nayak";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://Abhishek-VAIO\\MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=master;integratedSecurity=true";
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my error message is:

```
Sep 06, 2012 9:09:55 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:5cb4d70b-f644-4670-b7bc-a2312b8547b4
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2229)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.abhishek.Connect.main(Connect.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:35)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a JDBC driver that is dependent on a native SQL Server driver and need to add a path to the DLL it's dependent on (sqljdbc_auth.dll) to your library path in java.

To add this to settings of your Eclipse project (assuming you already have a SQL Server driver installed) do:

right click the project in Project Explorer -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> select `sqljdbc4.jar`, so it expands -> select Native library location -> Edit... -> enter `<location of SQL server driver on your machine>/sqljdbc_2.0/enu/auth/x64`-> OK.

Result should look like:

[image: Native library path location in Eclipse]