# Windows authentication with SQL Server using Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-authentication, sqljdbc

Follow up to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12304934/866785

I am also trying to connect to **SQL Server 2008 R2** with **Windows Authentication** using **Java**.

I have set the **PATH variable** to include

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64`

But I still get the error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path`

I am using **Netbeans IDE**, and also tried setting **-Djava.library.path**="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0  for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64" as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans)  but to no avail.

Comment: The error complains of a missing library, looks like. Have you added all the jars? Ah, I see now the previous question. You got the answer for eclipse but now need it for net beans?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans

Comment: @flup I tried the answer described in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans) but it didn't work for me.